# Node.js: Require a client certificate for a directory (and allow a retry)

Tags: node.js, certificate, ssl-certificate

I want to create a reverse proxy in node js, where I can require client certificates for certain parts of the site.

- The /secure section should require a client cert.
- The /nosecure section does not require a client cert.
- The user should be able to retry the client cert validation if he didn't provide a valid one before.

```js
    var options = {
        key: fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/key.pem'),
        cert: fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/cert.pem'),
        ca: fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/clientCA.pem'),
        requestCert: true
    };

    https.createServer(options, function (req, res) {
        //parse url
        req.parsedUrl = url.parse(req.url);

        //handle urls
        switch(req.parsedUrl.pathname) {
            case '/nosecure':
                /*
                 * This location does not require a client cert
                 */

                res.end('nosecure');
                break;
            case '/secure':
                /*
                 * This location requires a client certificate, which can be checked by getPeerCertificate()
                 * If no certificate is provided, the user will be redirected to secureError
                 */

                res.end('secure');
                break;
            case '/secureError':
                /*
                 * This location does not require a client cert
                 * It displays the error page, in case the client cert was not provided/validated on /secure.
                 */

                res.end('Certificate validation failed. <a href="/secure">Try again</a>');
                break;
            default:
                res.end('not found');       
                break;
        }
    }).listen(9000);
```

Normally you can only set these requirements on server level.
But I could manually check the cert in the secure section.

The problem however remains. I can not ask the client browser to send me the cert again.
This only happens once, when the SSL session is started.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm a noob myself but I'm playing around with the same thing.

Maybe something like

```
if (req.parsedUrl.pathname == '/secure' && !req.connection.getPeerCertificate().valid_to) req.parsedUrl.pathname = '/secureError';
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can simply allow unauthorized connections, and then logically check for authorization in order to allow access to some parts of your application.

Minimal Reproduceable Example

```js
const fs = require('fs')
const https = require('https')

const opts = {
    key: fs.readFileSync('some_key.pem'),
    cert: fs.readFileSync('some_cert.pem'),
    ca: [ fs.readFileSync('potentially_different_cert.pem') ],

    requestCert: true,
    rejectUnauthorized: false, // allow insecure connections
}

https.createServer(opts, (req, res) => {
    const cert = req.connection.getPeerCertificate()

    if (req.client.authorized) {
        //secure
    } else {
        //insecure
    }
}).listen(9000)
```